# jsPDF: addHTML method not working

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I created html table and tried to generate pdf using jsPDF.

I have used following code:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');  
pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('pdfTable'),function() {
  console.log('pdf generated');
});
pdf.save('pdfTable.pdf');
```

I am getting blank pdf file. Am I doing anything wrong?

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hzJgTFCh8xgxgRiy3gUq?p=info) for this.

Working [demo](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/#)  of jsPDF with addHTML function.

Comment: Solved it for you see my answer..

Answer (score 2):

Made working [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/enTDfltWHNZ6NjjCjkSA/preview) for this:
Update:
I have updated the plunker and made it work with `addHTML()` function:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
//var source = document.getElementById('table-container').innerHTML;
console.log(document.getElementById('table-container'));
var margins = {
   top: 25,
   bottom: 60,
   left: 20,
   width: 522
};
// all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
// 'inches' in this case
pdf.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
pdf.addHTML(document.body, margins.top, margins.left, {}, function() {
   pdf.save('test.pdf');
});
```

> You can see [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/enTDfltWHNZ6NjjCjkSA/preview) for more details.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but I need to use addHtml method only because I will be writing different content using other methods to the same pdf.

Comment: So you can make plain HTML by concatenating html string and finally use one fromhtml to print it..

Comment: I have updated the answer now using 'addHTML' function. @vinesh

Comment: Thanks. I'll check and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Change this in app.js:

```
  pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('pdfTable'),function() {
      });
  pdf.save('pdfTable.pdf');
```

for this one:

```
pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('pdfTable'),function() {
    pdf.save('pdfTable.pdf');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I took out everything but these:

```
<script src="//mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="//html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

then I used this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#pdfDiv").click(function() {

    var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');

    var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#rentalListCan': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
        }
    };

    pdf.addHTML($('#rentalListCan').first(), function() {
        pdf.save("rentals.pdf");
    });
    });
});
```

I can print the table... looks great with chrome, safari or firefox, however, I only get the first page if my table is very large.

Comment: Note that this worked for me only if both scripts are included in exact this order shown here. It doesn't work if you include html2canvas first. The reason is, that jsPDF overwrites some html2canvas methods, what I consider bad practice. So it only seems to work if html2canvas is included afterwards to re-define its methods properly. The same issue is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807755/jspdf-addhtml-method-not-working-with-no-error-message/34597797#34597797

Answer (score 0):

In app.js change:

```
  pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('pdfTable'),function() {

  });
  pdf.save('pdfTable.pdf');
```

to

```
  pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('pdfTable'),function() {
      pdf.save('pdfTable.pdf');
  });
```

If you see a black background, you can add to sytle.css "background-color: white;"

Comment: For some reason anything inside the `function()` ins't executing. The canvas is being rendered but the `pdf.save()` isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the getElementById() you should use querySelector()

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');  
pdf.addHTML(document.querySelector('#pdfTable'), function () {
  console.log('pdf generated');
});

pdf.save('pdfTable.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have test this in your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hzJgTFCh8xgxgRiy3gUq).

Just update your app.js

```
pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('pdfTable'), function() {
      pdf.save('pdfTable.pdf');
});
```

update your css file:

```
#pdfTable{
  background-color:#fff;
}
```